# SQL Join to select queries where have one to many relationship

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to create a sql query where I want to select all fields from one table, and one from another where they are joined by an id as a foreign key.

I have almost got there but this returns all image ids.

```
select p1.pub_id,i1.image_id 
from pub p1, images i1
where p1.pub_id = i1.pub_id
```

I need just one image record, the latest one.  Any ideas would be great. I have spent ages trying to get my head around this.

Comment: you have to have some condition which image_id (from many of them) it should be.

Comment: you may provide more information about your tables

Comment: You should really get used to using explicit `JOIN`s

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and the results  you expect?

Comment: To expand on everyone else's comments in order for your question to be answerable you need to provide some logic to decide which of the many image_ids you want to return. From your answer below are we able to infer that you want the maximum image_id?

Comment: @Ben yes this is what i was after

Answer (score 1):

So you spend hours not being able to do it and soon as your post it on here you work it out. anyhow.

```
select p1.pub_id, i1.image_id 
  from pub p1, images i1
 where i1.image_id = (select max(image_id) from images where pub_id = p1.pub_id)
```

Comment: @sufleR, please don't edit another users answer to change the code (especially when your answer is materially different). If you have an answer of your own then please add it.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your own question. You're doing a cartesian join here (and you're getting no errors because you're not using the explicit join syntax).

Answer (score -1):

```
select p1.pub_id,i1.image_id from pub p1, images i1where p1.pub_id = i1.pub_id(+)
```

works for oracle

Comment: The OP framed the question poorly and only explained the full requirement in a comment, but alas an OUTER JOIN is the exact opposite of what they want.